# HTML entity for the middle dot

Tags: html, html-entities

I'm looking for the html code for the dot. Not the dot that's at the end of sentences but the dot that's used to separate items horizontally.

```
Item 1 . Item 2 . Item 3
```

The traditional dot is centered on the bottom of the line while the dot I'm looking for is centered on the middle.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

It's called a [middle dot](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm): ·

HTML entities:

- `&middot;`
- `&#183;`
- `&#xb7;`

In CSS:

- `\00B7`

Answer (score 452):

There are actually seven variants of this:

| char | description | unicode | html | html entity | utf-8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| · | Middle Dot | U+00B7 | &#183; | &middot; | C2 B7 |
| · | Greek Ano Teleia | U+0387 | &#903; |  | CE 87 |
| • | Bullet | U+2022 | &#8226; | &bull; | E2 80 A2 |
| ‧ | Hyphenation Point | U+2027 | &#8321; |  | E2 80 A7 |
| ∙ | Bullet Operator | U+2219 | &#8729; |  | E2 88 99 |
| ● | Black Circle | U+25CF | &#9679; |  | E2 97 8F |
| ⬤ | Black Large Circle | U+2B24 | &#11044; |  | E2 AC A4 |

Depending on your viewing application or font, the "bullet" char may seem very similar to either the Middle Dot or the Bullet.

Comment: On a side note, the standard `list-style: disc` (and `text-security: disc` used for password fields), seems to be the Bullet `•` `&bull;`.

Comment: can we change the color of this dot?

Comment: @Satya, they're just text. Color away.

Comment: Thanks for the full detail! Exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Funny story: &dot; is not one of these.

Answer (score 150):

Do you mean bulletpoints? • • •

```
&bull;
```

Comment: Curious, how is this different than middle dot?

Comment: @Xonatron Middle dot is way smaller.

Answer (score 55):

That's a bullet: •

```
&bull;
```

Answer (score 29):

The semantically correct character is the **[Interpunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct)**, also known as **middle dot**, as HTML entity

```
&middot;
```

**Example**

> Home · Photos · About

---

You could also use the bullet point character, as HTML entity

```
&bull;
```

**Example**

> Home • Photos • About

Answer (score 5):

Try the HTML code:  `&#0149;`

Which will appear as: •

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using `&middot;`. You can color or size the dot according to the tags you wrap it with. For example, try and run this

```
<h2> I &middot; love &middot; Coding </h2>
```