# Rendering special characters in placeholder of input text box

Tags: angularjs, unicode, placeholder

I need to show [dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250381/html-code-for-the-dot) (●
) as the placeholder of the text input. But they are not rendering just showing the unicode in the placeholder. Please help me out

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" placeholder="{{somePlaceholder}}" />
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.somePlaceholder = '&#9679;&#9679;';
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8334/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's javaScript, you have to use `\u` escapes for Unicode characters.

```
$scope.somePlaceholder = '\u25cf\u25cf';
```

Or just write those dots literally (assuming the encoding of your script is declared properly by your web server).

```
$scope.somePlaceholder = '●●';
```